# Passing variables from form to form then creating new instance of class with passed data

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

this is my first post so be gentle. I am trying to create an instance of a class with specific variables in Form 2 when I click a button in Form 1. Then take the values that are now in the instance(test) of the class and change the text readout and progress lifebar based on those numbers. However when I run the application the text and progress bar go to 0 instead of their correct value. Furthermore, when I exit Form 2 and then click the button on Form 1 again it works fine. It's as if the test instance is being updated but Form 2 is not using the updated values. If I take the value for i and increment another progress bar by that amount it works so I know that I am passing values correctly into Form 2.

Edit: Deleted other post because it was on wrong forum.

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Fight_Game
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ChooseEasy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Combat_Form cf = new Combat_Form(5,8,19/*Need to send a lot of shit through here like monster health, and image to use.*/);
        cf.ShowDialog();
    }
 }
```

Form 2

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Fight_Game;

namespace Fight_Game
{
public partial class Combat_Form : Form
{
    static int i, j, k;
    public Combat_Form(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        i = x;
        j = y;
        k = z;
    }
    Class1 test = new Class1(i, j);

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EnemyLifeBar.Increment(i);
        PlayerLifeText.Text = "Life: " + test.Life.ToString() + "/100";
        PlayerLifeBar.Increment(test.Life);
    }


}
}
```

Class 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Fight_Game
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int Life;
        public int Mana;

        public Class1(int x, int y)
        {
            Life = x;
            Mana = y;
        }
}
```

Comment: This might not be your first post, so you might be lying, but it's ok, everybody lies, because you are asking to be gentle, so you know that (most of the) people here are arrogant, and do not help people that really need help, like you.

Comment: Why did you decide to declare `i`, `j` and `k` as `static` in the `Form2`? why are you creating an instance of `Class1` inside the class body? Why `Life` and `Mana` are public in `Class1`?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75302/passing-variables-from-form-to-form-then-creating-new-instance-of-class-with-pas

Comment: I guess there is no need for ijk to be static. I was attempting to make a constructor for class 1 in it's body, is this wrong? Life and Mana are public because I will want to change them based on a monsters attack function.